# Flex 4 fileReference selected image file dimmensions (width and height)

Tags: apache-flex, image, height, width, filereference

I use a fileReference.browse() to select an image file from the harddrive.

How can I check the Width and Height of the selected image file please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Load the fileReference.data into a Loader using loadBytes(). Then you'll have: sourceBMP:Bitmap = loader.content as Bitmap;

Here is a sample code:

MXML part:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <net:FileReference id="fileReference"
        select="fileReference_select(event);"
        complete="fileReference_complete(event);" />
</fx:Declarations>
<s:Button id="uplaodImageBtn"
    label="Upload Image"
    click="uplaodImageBtn_clickHandler()"/>
```

AS3 part:

```
private function uplaodImageBtn_clickHandler() : void {
    var arr:Array = [];
    arr.push(new FileFilter("Images", ".gif;*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.png"));
    fileReference.browse(arr);
}

private function fileReference_select(evt:Event):void {
    fileReference.load();
}

private function fileReference_complete(event:Event):void {
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loader_complete);
    loader.loadBytes(fileReference.data);
}

public function loader_complete (event:Event) : void {
    var sourceBMP:Bitmap = event.currentTarget.loader.content as Bitmap;
    Alert.show(sourceBMP.width + ', ' +sourceBMP.height);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Andi!

I wonder how much overhead such a technique would add to an application though.

But excellent answer. Thanks!

Comment: I see that you picked a different solution, that adds the Image to the display list. From your comment on Aug 10, I thought you did not want to do that.

Comment: Indeed. I had not seen the MXML part below: `<s:Image id="image" maxHeight="200" maxWidth="200"/>`. Was thinking `image` was just an AS variable that was not added to stage.

Answer (score 1):

From the context of Flex, I'm pretty sure that onc you get the results back from a browserr, it is only a byteArray.  In theory if you use that byteArray as the source for an image tag you'll be able to get the height and width that way, once you add that image to a container.

Otherwise, I do not believe there is an easy way to get such metadata info from local files using Flex.

Comment: It's a ByteArray, yes. I thought about creating an Image object programatically, but was worried about the overhead of doing it that way.

You are saying that even if I do that I have to use addChild to be able to measure it's content's dimmensions? I don't care about the container's size, just the Width and Height of the selected picture.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, there may be overhead creating an image object.  I do believe that an Image will not be measured until it is added to it's parent with the AddChild method, so height and width will be zero unless you set them explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to read the image.sourceWidth and image.sourceHeight if you wait for the image source property to update. This will give you the unscaled original values.

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.events.FlexEvent;     

        private function browseImage(event:MouseEvent):void {
            var arr:Array = [];
            arr.push(new FileFilter("Images", ".gif;*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.png"));
            imageFileReference.browse(arr);         
        }

        private function imageSelect(evt:Event):void {
            imageFileReference.load();
        }

        private function imageComplete(evt:Event):void {
            image.source = smallImageFileReference.data;
            image.addEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, getImageSize);                
        }

        private function getImageSize(evt:FlexEvent):void {
            image.removeEventListener(FlexEvent.UPDATE_COMPLETE, getImageSize);         
            imageWidth.text = image.sourceWidth + "px";
            imageHeight.text = image.sourceHeight + "px";
        }
    ]]>

</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <net:FileReference id="imageFileReference" 
        select="imageSelect(event)" 
        complete="imageComplete(event)"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%">

    <s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
        <s:Label fontWeight="bold" text="Width:" />
        <mx:Text id="imageWidth" />
    </s:HGroup> 

    <s:HGroup width="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
        <s:Label fontWeight="bold" text="Height:" />
        <mx:Text id="imageHeight" />
    </s:HGroup>

    <s:Image id="image" maxHeight="200" maxWidth="200" />
    <s:Button label="Browse for Image" click="browseImage(event)" />

</s:VGroup>
```